# Find number of male and female friends with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle (SQL*Plus) and I currently have the following tables:

```
USERS:
Id|Name|Gender  
1 |A   |M
2 |B   |F
3 |C   |M
4 |D   |F

FRIENDS
Id1|ID2
1  |2
1  |3
2  |3 
2  |4
2  |1
3  |1
3  |2
4  |2
```

How would I query,"For each user, find the number of male and female friends?"
I need an output that looks like this:

```
Id|Male Friends|Female Friends
1 |1           |1
2 |2           |1 
3 |1           |1
4 |0           |1
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: It's one of a dozen queries on the homework and I've been trying for hours.

Answer (score 2):

Make a query with two outer joins - one to male friends, and another one to female friends. Group by user ID:

```
SELECT u.Id, COUNT(m.Id) as MaleFriends, COUNT(f.Id) as FemaleFriends
FROM Users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Friends ff ON u.Id=ff.Id1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users m ON ff.Id2=m.Id AND m.Gender='M'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users f ON ff.Id2=f.Id AND f.Gender='F'
GROUP BY u.Id
```

The reason the counts of `m.Id` and `f.Id` would be different is that when a row of `FRIENDS` joins to a male friend, `f.Id` would be `NULL`, and vice versa. `COUNT` skips `NULL` values, producing the counts that you need.

Comment: What about people who have no friends? Starting from `Friends` instead of from `Users` means you'll be excluding them.

Comment: I'm getting this error:ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00904: "FF"."ID": invalid identifier

Comment: How can I group by ff.Id if ff is Friends and does not contain Id?

Comment: Actually, it gave the same results.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight My error. The query is correct. (You need an alias in the `SELECT u.ID` but I was wrong about the other.)